# How to load external video/image directory on to my web page via SpringMVC 4 programmatically?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

So far I was able to configure my resource (means my css and js )  as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.xx.xx.xxx")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

// Maps resources path to webapp/resources
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");   
}

...
```

and I was be able to load on the jsp side as follow:

```
<link href="<c:url value="../resources/css/mymaincss.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

what I really want to do is

on my video tag to display the thumbnail of the video prior starting the video and when the video starts display the video..

```
 <video width="560" height="340" controls>
    <img src="/home/myHomedir/thumbnailLocation/to/myvideo.jpg" />
    <source src="/home/myHomedir/videoLocationPath/to/myvideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="/home/myHomedir/videoLocationPath//myvideo.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
    </video>
```

how I can configure programmatically spring to read my external directory "/home/myHomedir/videoLocationPath/" plus the name of the video programmatically  in SpringMVC 4..

please leave example of code if it is too much of a disturb.

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

in SpringMVC the prefix inside the location instructs the lookup strategy, and there are four types

```
classpath: - resources loaded from the classpath.
file: - resources loaded as a URL, from the filesystem.
http: - resources loaded as a URL.
(none) - resources relative to the ROOT
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader

With that said, your conf could be something like

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/externalvideo/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/home/myHomedir/videoLocationPath");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/externalthumb/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/home/myHomedir/thumbnailLocation");
}
```

And analogous to your CSS include, the video tag should be something like

```
<video width="560" height="340" controls>
    <img src="<c:url value="../externalthumb/to/myvideo.jpg"/>" />
    <source src="<c:url value="../externalvideo/to/myvideo.mp4"/>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="<c:url value="../externalvideo/myvideo.ogv"/>" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
 </video>
```

Comment: I try your code yet I ended up seeing this on my source, also the video is not showing: here is the outcome of the source <source src="../externalvideo/2/1/14d8CtqVn.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>   also I have tryed to change as the link shows "file:///home/myHomedir/videoLocationPath" in stead of "file:/home/myHomedir/videoLocationPath"  any help on this?